# useEffect function is not called

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to render a component when certain states are triggered that are passed through Context API but after adding a `console.log` everywhere I noticed that the problem was with my `useEffect()` not being run and I don't know why:

```
interface ImageResponse {
  message: string;
}
interface ImageProps {
  breed: string;
  opened: boolean;
}
const BreedImageGenerator: FunctionComponent<ImageProps> = (opened, breed) => {
  const [randomImages, setRandomImage] = useState<ImageResponse[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRandomImages = async () => {
      const res: AxiosResponse = await axios.get<ImageResponse>(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random/4`
      );
      setRandomImage(res.data.message);
      console.log(randomImages);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box
      id="randomBreedImage">
      <Box>
        <ImageList sx={{ width: 500, height: 450 }}>
          <ImageListItem key="Subheader" cols={2}>
            <ListSubheader component="div">{breed}</ListSubheader>
          </ImageListItem>
          {randomImages &&
            randomImages.map((randomImage) => (
              <ImageListItem key={randomImage}>
                <img
                  src={randomImage}
                />
              </ImageListItem>
            ))}
        </ImageList>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default BreedImageGenerator;
```

I am sure that every prop is being passed correctly and as you can see there's a `console log` inside my `useEffect()` as well, but no luck. **Any ideas?**

---

I've tried even deleting everything from inside the `useEffect()` and keeping a `console.log` but nothing is being logged which is really strange because when I 'm calling the component (after those conditions that I mentioned earlier) all of the conditions evaluate to true.

---

This is where my component is being called:

```
<Grid item md="auto" xl={3.5}>
          {breeds &&
            breeds.map((breed) => {
              clickedBreed[breed.key] && isOpened && (
                <BreedImageGenerator
                  breed={breed.key}
                  opened={isOpened}
                  key={breed.key}
                />
              );
            })}
        </Grid>
```

And I know that all of these evaluate to true because when I replaced the `<BreedImageGenerator/>` with a `console.log()`, it was logging.

Also, doing this:

```
 const [randomImages, setRandomImage] = useState<ImageResponse[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRandomImages = async () => {
      const res: AxiosResponse = await axios.get<ImageResponse[]>(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random/4`
      );
      setRandomImage(res.data.message);
      
    };
    fetchRandomImages();

    console.log(randomImages);
  }, []);
```

changes nothing, my component is still not getting rendered.

Comment: Your ```breeds.map``` should return some array of undefined values, try adding ```return``` before ```clickedBreed[breed.key] && isOpened &&...``` so it will be ```return clickedBreed[breed.key] && isOpened &&...``` now.

Comment: @Oleksii I am getting this: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {breed, opened}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: @Oleksii just as a side note, I am using the same breeds.map in another component and it works just fine, so I doubt that there are undefined values in it.

Comment: You can try logging your ```breeds.map``` as you have now and see what it logs.

Comment: @Oleksii okay just did that and while clicking on the button that's supposed to change all states etc, it works perfectly, so the problem is with the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just fixed it, so I deleted the `opened` props as a test because I read somewhere that functional components only accept one prop passed to them (no idea why), and added the `breed` prop inside brackets, which I was avoiding because, since I am in typescript I was getting an error about it (as usual).
Also, **ALL** of the comments helped, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After you created the `fetchRandomImages()` function you need to call it.

E.g.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRandomImages = async () => {
      const res: AxiosResponse = await axios.get<ImageResponse>(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random/4`
      );
      setRandomImage(res.data.message);
      console.log(randomImages); //Do not call console.log right after setting state as it's still not ready.
    };
    fetchRandomImages() // You need to call the function here.
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     console.log(randomImages) //use it here.
  },[randomImages]) //this useEffect calls when randomImages changed.
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean inside the `useEffect()` but it still didn't run, the `console.log` showed nothing.

Comment: setting state is an async operation, it does not show immediately. I will update my answer to show you how to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring function inside useEffect does not mean it will execute, you have to execute by typing fetchRandomImages()